# Can I use a previous translation engine?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I already own a translation engine I created some years ago. I would like to know if I can use that engine to train a new engine using Microsfot Custom Translation.

I haven't bought Translator Text yet or any Azure producsts, so knowing whether if I can 'recycle' my old engine or not is something I will consider before buying any product.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the translator API v2.0 but it is not recommended. At the same time the translator hub had been retired since May. Which means you cannot improve the result with your document.

Comment: Translator Hub has been replaced with Custom Translator, allows you to build a custom translation engine. However, Custom Translator is limited to languages that Microsoft provides a base engine for.

Answer (score 0):

You train a Custom Translator system with previously translated documents. If your previous engine was a statistical system or neural translation system, you can use the same training material. If not, you could train on material that you have translated by hand or with your previous engine, or a mix of both. Custom Translator languages are limited to the languages Microsoft provides a base engine for.